# Recuperar gateway da rede?

Tags: java, android

Alguém conhece ou sabe alguma maneira de encontrar o endereço ip do `gateway` da rede ? O ip local eu sei que consigo recuperar com a classe `InetAddress`: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();`

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma classe chamada `DhcpInfo` dentro do pacote `android.net`, ele tem algumas variáveis com parâmetros da rede. Mas o problema que estes valores devem ser convertidos.

Imagem para descrever o cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código java:

```
package com.schogini.dhcp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.*;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class dhcpInfo extends Activity {
    public String   s_dns1 ;
    public String   s_dns2;     
    public String   s_gateway;  
    public String   s_ipAddress;    
    public String   s_leaseDuration;    
    public String   s_netmask;  
    public String   s_serverAddress;
    TextView info;
    DhcpInfo d;
    WifiManager wifii;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wifii= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        d=wifii.getDhcpInfo();

        s_dns1="DNS 1: "+String.valueOf(d.dns1);
        s_dns2="DNS 2: "+String.valueOf(d.dns2);    
        s_gateway="Default Gateway: "+String.valueOf(d.gateway);    
        s_ipAddress="IP Address: "+String.valueOf(d.ipAddress); 
        s_leaseDuration="Lease Time: "+String.valueOf(d.leaseDuration);     
        s_netmask="Subnet Mask: "+String.valueOf(d.netmask);    
        s_serverAddress="Server IP: "+String.valueOf(d.serverAddress);

        //dispaly them
        info= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infolbl);
        info.setText("Network Info\n"+s_dns1+"\n"+s_dns2+"\n"+s_gateway+"\n"+s_ipAddress+"\n"+s_leaseDuration+"\n"+s_netmask+"\n"+s_serverAddress);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.schogini.dhcp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".dhcpInfo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />  
</manifest>
```

Para fazer a conversão:

```
public String intToIp(int i) {    
   return ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF ) + "." +
               ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
               ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
               ( i & 0xFF) ;
}
```

Or

```
public String intToIp(int addr) {
    return  ((addr & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF) + "." + 
            ((addr >>>= 8) & 0xFF));
}
```

Fonte: [Programmatically getting the gateway and subnet mask details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387036/programmatically-getting-the-gateway-and-subnet-mask-details)

Comment: Wictor obrigado pela ajuda, tenho apenas uma dúvida, a linha que cria a instancia da classe WifiManager, está acusando o erro : Cannot resolve method getSystemService(java.lang.String)

Comment: Tente substituir wifii= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); por wifii =  (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar realizar as modificações hoje ainda !

Comment: Obrigado Wictor, seu código está funcionando. Será que você poderia me explicar esse método intoIP ? pois estou conseguindo pegar o ip do gateway, porém ele está retornando o ip de trás para frente. exemplo 1.200.168.192

Comment: Ele pega aquela numeração e converte para o formato ip, aquela tabela demonstra como isso funciona, de qualquer forma eu fiz outro método(O terceiro) invertendo a numeração, já que esta com a saída investida, e coloquei um segundo método do link que coloquei como referencia.